# mappingResources couldn't find the mapping file

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have my hibernate configuration files locate under a resources/hibernate directory folder. `resources` diretory folder is a source folder. When I declare `mappingResources` in Spring configuration like this:

```
<property name="mappingResources">
   <list>
      <value>classpath:hibernate/PojoA.hbm.xml</value>
   </list>
</property>
```

I got an error mention that PojoA.hbm.xml doesn't exists. May I know how this can be fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
<property name="mappingResources">
   <list>
      <value>hibernate/PojoA.hbm.xml</value>
   </list>
</property>
```